# Django/Bootstrap: form-check-inline not working

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

EDIT 1

I've tryed using bith crispy-forms and widegt-tweaks but it doen't works.

Seems that widget=forms.RadioSelect() is not compatible with use of these 2 libraries together...

---

I want to display radio button inline using Boostrap.

I've tryed to add bootstrap *form-check-inline* class by setting attrs attribute of Django widget.

But When I debug, *form-check-inline* is not applyed.
If I add *form-check-inline* class "manually" in div element containing radiobutton (see below) it works.

***template.html***

```
{{ form.eli_oui_ebo|as_crispy_field }}
```

***html page when inspected***

```
<div class="">                            ***<= here should be applyed form-check-inline class****
      <div class="form-check">
        <label for="id_id_eli_oui_ebo_0_1" class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="eli_oui_ebo" id="id_id_eli_oui_ebo_0_1" value="0"  class="test">
            Non
        </label>
      </div>
    
      <div class="form-check">
        <label for="id_id_eli_oui_ebo_0_2" class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="eli_oui_ebo" id="id_id_eli_oui_ebo_0_2" value="1"  class="test">
            Oui
        </label>
      </div>
</div>
```

***form.py***

````
self.fields['eli_oui_ebo'] = forms.TypedChoiceField(label = 'A eu, dans les 72h, un contact avec un malade Ebola confirmé par RT-PCR',widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'},),required=False,choices=[i for i in Thesaurus.options_list(1,'fr') if i != (None,'')], empty_value=None, disabled=DISABLED)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapper_class "form-check-inline"

Please refer crispy-bootstrap5/django source: https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5/blob/main/crispy_bootstrap5/templates/bootstrap5/layout/inline_field.html